# How does Stackoverflow remember what I entered in the input before I posted?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, user-input

When I start writing a question on Stackoverflow without finishing, I can leave the page, and when I return the input still is keeping what I had entered. How can this be done? Is a database absolutely necessary?

I would like to do something similar for a small webapp. Its a question-app where users answer questions with "No"/"Maybe"/"Yes". Depending on the answer, different points are awarded. When the user quits the test and returns, I would like to be still able to return the results of the last time he used it.

Can this be done completely in JavaScript?

[What the test looks like](https://martinhediger.000webhostapp.com/flexbox.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can store persistent information in `localStorage` - which is obviously local on the computer they're using.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: *Note* localStorage has ~10MB limit

Comment: @Justinas true - but given the usecase here (3 yes/no/maybe questions) I'm hoping the OP doesnt even get close :)

Comment: Unless it is media files, to save just text ~10MB is alot :)

Comment: Side note: when using localStorage, always have a fallback mechanism if the localStorage is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to across many systems/browser, you should use Database and store results and get back when access again.

If this feature restricted to the browser that you logged in, browsers [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)  alone will do the job.

> Can this be done completely in JavaScript?

Yes if you are using localstorage.